# Magento 2.3 Exception : Unable to unserialize value on some products URL Problem?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, url-rewrite, magento2.3.0, unserialize

Can any one help?

I have searched for solutions for Exception : **Unable to unserialize value**. however all of the solutions don't seem to work for me.

I have a bunch of products that when you try to make any changes to either the URL or assigned categories, it gives the following error:

> Unable to unserialize value.

I also don't seem to be able to make to the categories these products are in.

Other products are fine.

UPDATE: I think I have narrowed it down to the URL rewrites, as trying to edit one throws this error:

```
{"0":"Unable to unserialize value.","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/module-url-rewrite\/Model\/UrlRewrite.php(72): Magento\\Framework\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json->unserialize('{\"category_id\"\"...')\n#1 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/module-url-rewrite\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Url\/Rewrite.php(63): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Model\\UrlRewrite->getMetadata()\n#2 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/module-url-rewrite\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Url\/Rewrite\/Edit.php(61): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite->_getCategory()\n#3 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(108): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit->execute()\n#4 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#7 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(143): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/generated\/code\/Magento\/UrlRewrite\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Url\/Rewrite\/Edit\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#11 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(159): Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(99): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http), Object(Magento\\UrlRewrite\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Url\\Rewrite\\Edit\\Interceptor))\n#13 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#15 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#17 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#19 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callParent('launch', Array)\n#20 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#21 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)\n#22 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#23 \/var\/www\/vhosts\/valvesonline.co.uk\/web\/pub\/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#24 {main}","url":"\/admin_19rhxf\/admin\/url_rewrite\/edit\/id\/1900359\/key\/33ad257f75a7435d4a4f94b45e01e3803cba4c1262423d81c3373b6513facfb9\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Refer: https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it didn't work for me, I managed to solve it however with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching long and hard and not finding a solution, I have managed to work out a way to solve this which thankfully works.

I disable the problem product, save and duplicate.

Delete the problem product.

Edit, enable and save duplicate product.

With the duplicate product I changed the SKU and URL to the old product's details.

If anyone has any similar issues with any products, it might be worth trying out.